# GeoPandas reproject shapefile

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I have a `geotiff` image from `Paris` metropolitan area I have generated from MODIS data in Google Earth Engine with the following projection

```
data_.rio.crs
CRS.from_wkt('PROJCS["MODIS Sinusoidal",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]')
```

[image]

Now I have the shapefile of Paris metropolitan area. I would like to set the right `crs=myCrs` for the shapefile but I do not know which one it is right.

```
# Get images from Paris 
gdf = gpd.read_file('paris.shp')     ## Paris metro area
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=myCrs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `epsg=myCrs` with `'PROJCS["MODIS Sinusoidal",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Sinusoidal"],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",0],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'`

You could also use the rio CRS from your raster (see excerpt from below mentioning rio crs are compatible with Geopandas)

According to the Geopandas docs, https://geopandas.org/projections.html.

> Other formats
>
> Next to the EPSG code mentioned above, there are also other ways to
> specify the CRS: an actual pyproj.CRS object, a WKT string, a PROJ
> JSON string, etc. Anything that is accepted by
> pyproj.CRS.from_user_input can by specified to the crs
> keyword/attribute in GeoPandas.
>
> Also compatible CRS objects, such as from the rasterio package, can be
> passed directly to GeoPandas.

In first example, I use the WKT